# Stepwise population evaluation using genetic algorithm in R

Tags: r, optimization, genetic-algorithm

I am trying to optimize a complex model that takes several hours to run on a remote computer. Setting up a GA script on the remote computer is not possible. As such, I was thinking of using the following approach:

1. Create an initial population of solutions on my local computer
2. Send this population to the remote computer and evaluate each member
3. Retrieve the fitness values for the population from the remote computer
4. Use the previous population and its fitness values to generate the next population on my local computer (likely by supplying the previous population as the initial population to a new GA run and creating a fitness function that simply checks a lookup table for the previously evaluated solutions).
5. Repeat steps 2-4 until I am satisfied with the convergence.

However, I haven't been able to find any of the popular R GA functions that allow this "stepwise" approach.

Furthermore, when I try a small test of this "stepwise" approach using GA::ga (my preferred algorithm since it seems to be the best documented and maintained), I don't get consistent results.

For example...

```
 library(GA)
 Rastrigin <- function(x1, x2) 20 + x1^2 + x2^2 - 10*(cos(2*pi*x1) + cos(2*pi*x2))
 fit <- function(x) -Rastrigin(x[1], x[2])

 suggestedSol <- matrix(c(rep(0,10), seq(0.5, 5, 0.5)), 
                        nrow = 10, ncol = 2, byrow = FALSE)
```

Here I provide GA::ga with an initial population and `seed = 333`, and I run just 3 generations.

```
 GA1 <- ga(type = "real-valued", 
           fitness = fit,
           lower = c(-5, -5), 
           upper = c(5, 5), 
           suggestions = suggestedSol,
           popSize = 10, maxiter = 3, seed = 333)
 iter3 <- GA1@population
 iter3
       [,1]     [,2]
  [1,]    0 4.648199
  [2,]    0 1.244214
  [3,]    0 1.000000
  [4,]    0 3.927499
  [5,]    0 1.087419
  [6,]    0 1.917443
  [7,]    0 1.076341
  [8,]    0 1.785816
  [9,]    0 1.995138
 [10,]    0 1.041109
```

And then here I do the same, but run just to the second generation:

```
GA2 <- ga(type = "real-valued", 
          fitness = fit,
          lower = c(-5, -5), 
          upper = c(5, 5), 
          suggestions = suggestedSol,
          popSize = 10, maxiter = 2, seed = 333)
iter2 <- GA2@population
```

...and then I use the saved second generation as the initial population for a new run, running just one more generation (to the theoretical third generation).

```
GA3 <- ga(type = "real-valued", 
          fitness = fit,
          lower = c(-5, -5), 
          upper = c(5, 5),  
          suggestions = iter2,
          popSize = 10, maxiter = 2, seed = 333)
stepwise3 <- GA3@population
stepwise3
      [,1]     [,2]
 [1,]    0 2.113191
 [2,]    0 1.007642
 [3,]    0 1.072837
 [4,]    0 1.000000
 [5,]    0 1.141010
 [6,]    0 3.246744
 [7,]    0 1.079777
 [8,]    0 1.946409
 [9,]    0 1.087419
[10,]    0 1.769360
```

`iter3` and `stepwise3` are not identical, even though `seed` was set the same, and they theoretically came from the same previous generation. What am I missing? If this doesn't work, then how can I apply this "stepwise" approach to my broader problem?

Comment: I don't know GA packages in R so I could not help you with that. I suspect your lack of consistency comes from the seed in your third call. It's you are reseting your RNG between the second and the third iteration. You may want to try not input the seed when you call `ga` to compute `GA3` from `GA2`. However, even if it works there (i'm not sure of that) I suspect it wouldn't on a remote setup. It should work if you decompose all the iterations explicitly and provide seeds. I hope that helps.

Comment: It does not seem to work to not specify the seed in the `GA3`call. But I'm pretty sure that is the explanation for the inconsistency.